# How can I wrap rails application for deployment and hand off?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

Okay I know how to package Java restful services for example in the war form. But for how about ROR? I need to hand off my ROR services to another team and don't want them to know about my code. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you "want them to know about [your] code"? Is it bad? If you just don't want them to "steal" it then what you need is a contract, not some way to obfuscate the code.

Comment: I just want them to consume my service by calling it through their client side. They only have a UI stack.

Comment: You can't, its not gonna happen. By the way, if you want to, you could just decompile the .war and have a good look at it. Get a contract and/or just hand over your code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ll switch to Java for the service then. They have ROR UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's possible to [wrap a jruby project as a War file](http://caldersphere.rubyforge.org/warbler/), you're out of luck otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I ll try Java web services for back-end now. Front end would remain in ROR for them.